# Use two different forms in same template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write a condition where if 1st part is ok then 2nd part will show.I wrote my forms.py in a following way :

```
class SubmissionForm(forms.Form):
      first_name=forms.CharField(max_length=120, required=True)
      last_name=forms.CharField(max_length=120, required=True)
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    file1 = forms.Field(label='File1', widget = forms.FileInput,required = True )
    file2 = forms.Field(label='File1', widget = forms.FileInput,   required = True )
```

In my views.py:

```
def submission(request):
validform=False
title="Please submit your data"
form = SubmissionForm(request.POST)
contextsumission={"title":title, "form":form}
if form.is_valid():
    first_name = form.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
    last_name = form.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
    validform=True
    if validform:
        contextupload={"title":"Please upload your files","valid":True}
        return render(request, 'submission.html', contextupload)
    form2 = UploadForm(request.FILES)
    contextsumission={"title":'Upload files', "form2":form2}
    if form2.is_valid():
        file1 = form2.request.FILES.get("file1")
        file2 = form2.request.FILES.get("file2")
        contextsumission={"title":"Thank you for your data submission"}

return render(request, 'submission.html', contextsumission)
```

And I have tried to write my template in a following way

```
                    {% if valid %}
                    <h1 class ='text-align-center', style="color: blue;"> {{ title }} </h1>
                    <form method ='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data" action =''> {% csrf_token %}
                        {{form2|crispy}}
                        <input class='btn btn-primary', type='submit', value='Upload'>
                    </form>

                {% else %}
                    <h1 class ='text-align-center', style="color: blue;"> {{ title }} </h1>

                    <form method ='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data" action =''> {% csrf_token %}
                        {{form|crispy}}
                        <input class='btn btn-primary', type='submit', value='Submit'>
                    </form>

                {% endif %}
```

I can see my SubmissionForm clearly in template but after pressing submit button I want to show file upload form but it is not working.
Anyone can please tell me where I need to change my code?
Thanks
Paul

Yes I have realized that and modified my code but still I have problem and def submission function is not validating two forms!! That means when ever I am trying to do form2.is_valid(), is returning false.

```
def submission(request):
title="Please submit your data"
form = SubmissionForm(request.POST)
contextsubmission={"title":title, "form":form}
if form.is_valid():
    first_name = form.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
    last_name = form.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
    form2 = UploadForm(request.FILES)
    contextsubmission ={"title":"Please upload your files","form2":form2,"valid":True}
    if form2.is_valid():
        file1 = form2.request.FILES.get("file1")
        file2 = form2.request.FILES.get("file2")
        contextbsumission={"title":"Thank you for your data submission"}
return render(request, 'submission.html', contextsubmission)
```

Comment: Please post the actual code you are using. This one cannot work at all since you try to add a variable named `form` which you don't define into your context.

Comment: Hi Selcuk sorry for that but I have updated my code which is working atleast 1st part